# floatValue for CGFloat

Tags: cocoa, slider

I have a NSSlider that is attempting to convert a regular float into a CGFloat.  The code that I am using:

```
CGFloat testing = [mainSlider floatValue];
```

However this simply makes the testing variable "0.00" when I attempt to log it.

```
NSLog(@"%f", testing);
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this would happen?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. check that mainSlider isn't nil
2. <strike>try this just in case (can't remember if CGFloat is a double or not)</strike>:

   NSLog(@"%f", (double)testing);
3. Check that the variable isn't being shadowed like this:

   ```
   CGFloat testing = 0.0;
   if(YES){
       CGFloat testing = [mainSlider floatValue];
       //should be: testing = [mainSlider floatValue];
   }
   NSLog(@"testing = %f", testing); //this will print "testing = 0.000000"
   ```

Comment: Note that casting to `double` will not restore any precision lost when `floatValue` converted the value to single-precision. Better to just use `doubleValue`.

Comment: Also, the cast to (double) is unnecessary. The c language does that implicitly when calling a vargs function with a float argument.

Comment: mainSlider isn't nil, just for some weird reason it doesn't transfer into a CGFloat. When I log it like: NSLog(@"%f", [mainSlider floatValue]), it returns the result. But not when I create a CGFloat from it.

Comment: Another wrinkle in the whole `double` casting debate is `CGFloat` is `typedef`ed to `float` when running in 32-bit mode, but `double` when running in 64-bit mode.  So, in 32-bit mode, `CGFloat testing = [mainSlider doubleValue];` squashes it in to a single-precision `float` type anyways...

Comment: Okay, this problem is just getting stranger and stranger.  The same code (the same exact code) runs in every other function EXCEPT the one that I try to get it to run in.  For some reason drawRect:(NSRect)rect just doesn't seem to like that code...

Comment: In that case, it could be shadow variables. Check to see if there are any other variables named "testing" in drawRect.

Comment: @Tom Dalling  It logs testing = 0.000000, does that mean that there is another variable called testing?

Comment: Possibly, but not definitely.

Comment: Even when I set the other function to be called from drawRect, it still outputs 0 for the slider value. I am using the following code to call the function: [self changeItem:self]; Does anyone know why this would be caused? The IBAction is usually called by a NSSlider, which may be the problem.